# Custom wpf checkbox click event not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

Sure Im missing something simple but I have overridden a checkbox as a user control so I can use different images as its bullet decorators. Seems to work ok but doesnt respond to any click or checked events. I need it to display the bound popup upon the click evnt but not change the bullet decorator images.

Also my binding seems to be broken as when the click even fires (once it works) it should present a popup with the bound data. WarningList is my data to bind and when debugging it shows its populated correctly, just not bound correctly I believe

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Dev.App.Views.Controls.StatusResultCheckBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Dev.App.Views.Converters"
             x:Name="Root"
             d:DesignHeight="50"
             d:DesignWidth="50"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:WarningListFilterByOperationTypeConverter x:Key="WarningListFilterByOperationTypeConverter" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StatusResultNone">
            <Viewbox Width="20" Height="20">
                <Grid/>
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StatusResultWarning">
            <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <Viewbox Width="20" Height="20">
                        <Grid>
                            <Path Data="F1M874.094,289.369L854.3,254.63C854.028,254.151 853.515,253.856 852.958,253.856 852.403,253.856 851.89,254.151 851.617,254.63L831.824,289.369C831.555,289.84 831.559,290.416 831.835,290.883 832.111,291.348 832.618,291.634 833.165,291.634L872.752,291.634C873.299,291.634 873.805,291.348 874.081,290.883 874.357,290.416 874.361,289.84 874.094,289.369z"
                              Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFCCE00" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" StrokeThickness="0.5">
                            </Path>
                            <Path Data="M855.653,287.189L850.264,287.189 850.264,282.745 855.653,282.745 855.653,287.189z M855.653,279.41L850.264,279.41 850.264,266.077 855.653,266.077 855.653,279.41z"
                              Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Black" Width="3" Height="10" Margin="0.5,3,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" StrokeThickness="0.5">
                            </Path>
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>
                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                <Popup Name="WarningMessagePopup"
                               Width="{Binding ElementName=ListBox, Path=ActualWidth}"
                               Height="200"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalOffset="50"
                               PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsChecked}"
                               StaysOpen="False"
                               VerticalOffset="10">
                    <TextBox VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WarningListFilterByOperationTypeConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                                <Binding Path="OperationType" />
                                <Binding Path="DataContext.WarningList" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                </Popup>
            </BulletDecorator>
        </DataTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
            <ContentControl Name="Content" />
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusResultCheckMode, ElementName=Root}" Value="None">
                    <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource StatusResultNone}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StatusResultCheckMode, ElementName=Root}" Value="Warning">
                    <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource StatusResultWarning}" />
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasStatus, ElementName=Root}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="StatusResultVisibilityStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent">
                            <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                                <Viewbox Width="20" Height="20">
                                    <Grid />    
                                </Viewbox>
                            </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        </BulletDecorator>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsInStatusNone.Value}" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsInStatusWarning.Value}" Value="True" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     IsChecked="True"
                     Style="{StaticResource StatusResultVisibilityStyle}"/>
        <ContentControl Grid.Column="0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Width="20" Height="20"
                        Template="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Called from my main page as follows. (nested inside a Listbox)

```
<controls:StatusResultCheckBox Grid.Column="3"
    IsInStatusWarning="{Binding Path=IsInStatusWarning.Value}"
    IsInStatusNone="{Binding Path=IsInStatusNone.Value}"
    HasStatus="{Binding Path=HasStatus.Value}"
    IsRunning="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.IsRunning.Value}"/>
```

The code behind the user control...

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Dev.App.Views.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for StatusResultCheckBox.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class StatusResultCheckBox : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusResultCheckModeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StatusResultCheckMode", typeof(StatusResultCheckMode), typeof(StatusResultCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(StatusResultCheckMode.None));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsRunningProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("IsRunning", typeof(bool), typeof(StatusResultCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(false, IsRunningPropertyChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasStatusProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("HasStatus", typeof(bool), typeof(StatusResultCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(false, IsRunningPropertyChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsInStatusWarningProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("IsInStatusWarning", typeof(bool), typeof(StatusResultCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(false, IsRunningPropertyChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsInStatusNoneProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("IsInStatusNone", typeof(bool), typeof(StatusResultCheckBox), new PropertyMetadata(false, IsRunningPropertyChanged));

        private static void IsRunningPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var statusResultCheckBox = d as StatusResultCheckBox;

            if (statusResultCheckBox != null)
            {
                if (statusResultCheckBox.IsRunning)
                {
                    if (statusResultCheckBox.IsInStatusWarning)
                    {
                        statusResultCheckBox.StatusResultCheckMode = StatusResultCheckMode.Warning;
                        statusResultCheckBox.HasStatus = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        statusResultCheckBox.StatusResultCheckMode = StatusResultCheckMode.None;
                        statusResultCheckBox.HasStatus = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public StatusResultCheckBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public StatusResultCheckMode StatusResultCheckMode
        {
            get { return (StatusResultCheckMode)GetValue(StatusResultCheckModeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StatusResultCheckModeProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool IsRunning
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsRunningProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsRunningProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool HasStatus
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(HasStatusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HasStatusProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool IsInStatusWarning
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsInStatusWarningProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsInStatusWarningProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool IsInStatusNone
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsInStatusNoneProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsInStatusNoneProperty, value); }
        }
    }

    public enum StatusResultCheckMode
    {
        None,
        Warning
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like this, it probably will be easier if you just apply a style to a existing checkbox.

You can get the default style from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319(v=vs.110).aspx) and change what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up refactoring all this code and simplifying. Basically styled a togglebutton.

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource WarningStyle}"/>
```

And in the resource file...

```
<Style x:Key="WarningStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Path Data="F1M874.094,289.369L854.3,254.63C854.028,254.151 853.515,253.856 852.958,253.856 852.403,253.856 851.89,254.151 851.617,254.63L831.824,289.369C831.555,289.84 831.559,290.416 831.835,290.883 832.111,291.348 832.618,291.634 833.165,291.634L872.752,291.634C873.299,291.634 873.805,291.348 874.081,290.883 874.357,290.416 874.361,289.84 874.094,289.369z"
                          Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFFCCE00" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" StrokeThickness="0.5">
                    </Path>
                    <Path Data="M855.653,287.189L850.264,287.189 850.264,282.745 855.653,282.745 855.653,287.189z M855.653,279.41L850.264,279.41 850.264,266.077 855.653,266.077 855.653,279.41z"
                          Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Black" Width="3" Height="10" Margin="0.5,3,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" StrokeThickness="0.5">
                    </Path>
                    <Popup Name="WarningMessagePopup"
                           Width="425"
                           Height="150"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalOffset="22"
                           PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                           IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsChecked}"
                           StaysOpen="False"
                           VerticalOffset="7">
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WarningList}">
                            <ListBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F8FCFF"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ListBox.Style>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WarningListFilterByOperationTypeConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                                                    <Binding Path="Count" />
                                                    <Binding Path="Message" />
                                                </MultiBinding>
                                            </TextBlock.Text>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsInStatusWarning.Value}" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```